# Adding restrictions to ACLs yields empty results for queries in Jackrabbit Oak

Tags: security, jcr, jackrabbit, jcr-sql2, jackrabbit-oak

Using Jackrabbit Oak, I've been attempting to configure security through `SecurityProvider` and `SecurityConfiguration`s. In particular, I've been using the restrictions which generally works as expected. However, when dealing with `JCR-SQL2` queries, more gets filtered out than expected.

**Details**

It can be reproduced with the repository below.

```
/
  node          [nt:unstructured]
    subnode     [nt:unstructured]
```

On `node`, I add an access control entry with privilege `JCR_ALL` for `user` together with a restriction for `rep:glob` -> `""`, such that `user` do not have access to any children of `node`.

It works as expected when using `session.getNode`:

- `session.getNode("/node")` returns the node
- `session.getNode("/node/subnode")` throws `PathNotFoundException` as expected due to the restriction.

However, when I execute the following `JCR-SQL2` query:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured]
```

I get **no results back**. Here I would have expected to get `/node`, as it is otherwise available when using `session.getNode`.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Repository repository = new Jcr().with(new MySecurityProvider()).createRepository();
    Session session = repository.login(new UserIdCredentials(""));    // principal is "SystemPrincipal.INSTANCE"

    // Create nodes
    Node node = session.getRootNode().addNode("node", "nt:unstructured");
    node.addNode("subnode", "nt:unstructured");

    // Add access control entry + restriction
    AccessControlManager acm = session.getAccessControlManager();
    JackrabbitAccessControlList acl = (JackrabbitAccessControlList) acm
        .getApplicablePolicies("/node").nextAccessControlPolicy();
    Privilege[] privileges = new Privilege[]{acm.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_ALL)};
    Map<String, Value> restrictions = new HashMap<String, Value>() {{put("rep:glob", new StringValue(""));}};
    acl.addEntry(new PrincipalImpl("user"), privileges, true, restrictions);
    acm.setPolicy("/node", acl);
    session.save();

    // executes query
    RowIterator rows = repository.login(new UserIdCredentials("user")).getWorkspace().getQueryManager()
        .createQuery("SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured]", Query.JCR_SQL2).execute().getRows();
        System.out.println("Number of rows: " + rows.getSize());  //Prints 0
}
```

If one were to remove `restrictions` from the code above, both `node` and `subnode` appears in the query results as expected.

`MySecurityProvider` uses `ConfigurationParameters.EMPTY` and the default implementations of all `SecurityConfiguration`s, except for `AuthenticationConfiguration` which I've implemented myself:

```
class MyAuthenticationConfiguration extends AuthenticationConfigurationImpl {
    public MyAuthenticationConfiguration(SecurityProvider securityProvider) {
        super(securityProvider);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public LoginContextProvider getLoginContextProvider(ContentRepository contentRepository) {
        return new LoginContextProvider() {
            @NotNull
            public LoginContext getLoginContext(Credentials credentials, String workspaceName) {
                String userId = ((UserIdCredentials) credentials).getUserId();
                Set<Principal> principalSets = new HashSet<>();
                if (userId.isEmpty()) {
                    principalSets.add(SystemPrincipal.INSTANCE);
                } else {
                    principalSets.add(new PrincipalImpl(userId));
                }
                Map<String, ? extends Principal> publicPrivileges = new HashMap<>();
                AuthInfoImpl authInfoImpl = new AuthInfoImpl(userId, publicPrivileges, principalSets);
                Subject subject = new Subject(true, principalSets, Collections.singleton(authInfoImpl), new HashSet<Principal>());
                return new PreAuthContext(subject);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I am using Jackrabbit Oak version 1.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out be a bug in Jackrabbit Oak - [Link to issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-7997).

This has been resolved as of version 1.12.0